# Full-text searching, how fast one can find "Linus Torvalds" into the linux kernel?

Tags: performance, grep, linux-kernel, file-search

Three things:

- Currently, what are the fastest full-text search tools?
- Are there full-text search tools capable of reporting fullpaths of files containing hit(s), FAST?
- Is Linus Torvalds right about AVX512 being garbage, can we do better than AVX2?

A full-text search enthusiast here, my question is what tools are out there that can perform HIGH-SPEED searches?
AFAIK, there are only two, https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep and my [NyoTengu](https://www.overclock.net/threads/cpu-benchmark-finding-linus-torvalds.1754066/page-2#post-28650381), are there other tools?
I find this question unanswered since early x86 days when 80286's 16bit Assembler dominated the searches, nowadays with 512bit Assembler at hand, how things have changed?! This is the question/**quest**!

As a follow-up, how fast AVX512 can perform, my current record (traversing the linux kernel 5.8.5) is 11.1 GB/s on AVX2 laptop, can we reach 15 GB/s on e.g. Intel Core i5-1035G4?!

Also, I see many users, including myself, asking for a tool searching into a tree containing 20,000++ files, and reporting the fullpaths of files containing a given needle, wonder is there a tool combining them all (similar to TARring) with a (8,8) bytes offset (start,end) index pair for each file, thus current C source of NyoTengu could easily be enhanced so it can quickly say the reported hit/offset (which is 8 bytes) falls between those two!? I fully expect, with modern 5GB/s nvme SSDs, such searches to saturate those 5GB/s.

Comment: Your question lacks focus and it's off-topic at least in part. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Also, here's a quote from first paragraph in ripgrep's README: _"ripgrep is similar to other popular search tools like The Silver Searcher, ack and grep."_

Comment: @gronostaj
It is confusing, the link states:

"Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

computer hardware,
computer software, or
..."

The kernel.org directs to superuser.com, what is exactly the off-topicness, my interest as a user pushing the limits did lead me here, superuser, that is!

Comment: SuperUser is a Q&A site, not a forum. This model works well for answering specific questions, but not for open-ended discussion. Please read the _"... it is not about..."_ section in the previous link and also this one: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @gronostaj
I still see no problem, but if it bothers you, delete it, go on, won't ask no more.